# multithreading deadlock

Tags: multithreading, deadlock

Thread 1:

```
putQ
setFlag
```

Thread 2：

```
while (1) {
waitFlag
processQ
clearFlag
}
```

This is an interview question.  I am not sure whether there is a while loop for Thread 1. 
But the answer is like when Thread 2 re-enter the while loop, two threads go into deadlock.

Can anyone tell me what's condition for deadlock? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not seeing it... unless it's the trivial case that Thread 1 only runs once and thread 2 will wait forever after that.

Comment: Are you sure you mean "deadlock" and not "race-condition"?

Comment: It may be race condition, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the OP's comments are correct:

1. **@Gray**: This is most likely NOT a dead-lock, but a race condition. Yet the application is stuck not processing the queue, so it's a lock.
2. **@Wug**: It is probably the "trivial case" where while `thread 1` has put in the queue and updated the flag, `thread 2` will never notice. See course of action below.

Potential lock situation:

- T2: `ProcessQ` Element 0 (processing a former element)
- T1: `PutQ` Element 1
- T1: `SetFlag`
- T2: `ClearFlag`
- T2: `waitFlag`

Element 1 might never be processed.

**EDIT:**

Of course, the next question would be: `how do you fix that?`

The answer would be with a `Conditional Variable` (see `pthread_cond_init` and others for details):

*Thread 1:*

```
PutQ
LockMutex
SetFlag
CondSignal
UnlockMutex
```

*Thread 2:*

```
while (1) {
    LockMutex
    while (FlagIsUnset)
       CondWait
    FlagUnset
    UnlockMutex
    ProcessQ
}
```

Comment: do you mean that there is only one element can be put in the Q?

Comment: No, In the example given, if element 1 is the last element inserted, it will never be processed.

Answer (score 0):

The one problematic scenario I see is when Thread 1 (`T1`) calls the code in question twice in a short period of time. Here is a possible course of action:

- `T2: waitFlag`
- `T1: putQ`
- `T1: setFlag`
- `T2: processQ`
- `T1: putQ`
- `T1: setFlag`
- `T2: clearFlag`

If `T1` never again puts anything into the queue, `T2` will never process the second item. But it's not a deadlock.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there's a loop around the first block, I believe the example is trying to call attention to the importance of counting in semaphores.  The "flag" in the example does not count, so multiple passes through the first loop put multiple items in the queue but the flag can only be "set" once and so the second loop can only be triggered once.  A semaphore would count up once for each `V` in the upper loop so that the second loop would run as many times as needed while reducing the count with `P`.